# Good (android based?) music center+nav replacement for 2008 Audi A4 Quattro?

Tags: audio, audi

I have 2008 Audi A4 Quattro with the [RNS-E Navigation System Plus](http://www.satnavsystems.com/main/audi-a4-dvd-navigation-system-rns-e/) built in. Also, I have an Ipod connector in the glove compartment. I am interested in replacing that whole system with something newer and better - and not Apple related.

Are there any compatible systems with Android based interfaces (so I can install my own apps (in my prefered navigation app)...), which can stream music via bluetooth and have the entire phone pairing feature? Also if it can get on WiFi (so I can tether to it...) it would be a bonus, and of course touchscreen, AUX, SDCARD (HC), USB...

Am I asking for too much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.pioneerelectronics.com/PUSA/Car/AppRadio/AppRadio+3+(SPH-DA210)

I have spent a bit of time looking at this head unit, which lets you plug in your iPod/iPhone and also supports Android (you could just buy a cheap Android phone if you don't already have one). Not quite a native Android unit but I think is fairly close to the mark and on it's 3rd revision I think it's a good bit of kit although I have only played with a demo in Halfords.

On the subject specifically of navigation http://www.appradioknows.com/navigation/

Comment: Also good value for money! =)